# Jenkins Plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and trying to understand the use of Plugins.
I have installed Jenkins on a server which already has few software's like Git,terraform.
Do I still need to install Plugins for Jenkins explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you use git as a shell command. 
`sh "git"`

If you want to use a plugin functionality, you need to install it.